# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) error for a URL webview in xcode and swift

Tags: swift, xcode, url, webview, null

I am new to xcode and Swift and I am getting an error

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

I've tried searching similar questions on stackoverflow and I saw that people's responses were that it's because the url is not valid, so it's returning `nil`.  However, I am using https://google.com and I am still getting the same error.  This is all my code so far.  I am only trying to load a single webpage into the view controller.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")

    myWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: You should check the console output when you get some runtime errors. You may find **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil...**, which is caused by forced unwrapping indicated by `!`. If `url!` is not the case, then `myWebView: UIWebView!`. Check if `myWebView` is surely connected in Interface Builder. Anyway, you can find many, many so many articles discussing the same situations and some of them include _how to debug_.

Comment: Yes, I saw the nil error in the console and I've been checking various documentations on the errors that I found throughout this process.

Comment: Happy to hear you solve it. But your SOLUTION would be better placed as answer.

Comment: I reposted my solution as an answer.  I'm still new to stackoverflow too, so I wasn't sure where to put it.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at various documentations and videos on the errors I found that the issue was that I was writing my code in the wrong file for the viewController as the viewController that I was targeting was a second one that I created to be access from the original one. Therefore, for anyone else who is completely new development and to xcode and swift. The original viewController.swift file is only for the first viewController. A new viewController.swift file must be created to add code to any subsequently created viewControllers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your outlet is not connected properly and also always try to avoid doing force unwrapped. In order to prevent your crash you can use below check:-

> ```
> guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com") else { return }
> myWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))
> ```

or

> ```
> if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com") {
>   myWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))
> }
> ```

Comment: Still you are seeing the crash??